# Override format in Material UI KeyboardDatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to override the default format provide by Mui Datepicker (current default is "**/**/____") by using mask but the code won't let me type anything if I use mask?

```
 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          data-testid={props.name}
          className={styles.DateValueField}
          margin="normal"
          mask = {"/\d/, /\d/, ' / ', /\d/, /\d/, ' / ', /\d/, /\d/"}
          format="dd / MM / yy"
          value={dateValue}
          onChange={dateSelected}
          placeholder={"DD / MM / YY"}
          variant={"inline"}
          disableToolbar
          autoOk 
        />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mask will be generated and applied automatically from the format passed. So please, make sure that your formats are easy to input from keyboard. And it is still possible to fully customize mask, checkout this example:

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
  format="dd/MM/yyyy"
- mask={[/d/, /d/, "/", /d/, /d/, "/", /d/, /d/, /d/, /d/]}
/>
```

If you look at the DatePicker API you'll find that there is no mask property, so you must use the format property instead.

Comment: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/upgrading-to-v3#-and-now-no-more-need-in-mask-prop-